# mod_rewrite rule broken if PHP file is named as the rewrite pattern

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect all requests like:

```
/xml/doSomething?arg=value
```

To:

```
/xml.php?action=doSomething&arg=value
```

I tried this simple rule:

```
RewriteEngine
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^xml/([^/]+)[/]? xml.php?action=$1 [R=302,L,QSA]
```

But it not works. The `xml.php` is executed with `arg=value` param only. The problem is that there is that file named `xml.php`, as the first part of my rule. In fact, if I change the rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^asd/([^/]+)[/]? xml.php?action=$1 [R=302,L,QSA]
```

And I point to:

```
/asd/doSomething?arg=value
```

I'm correctly redirected to:

```
/xml.php?action=doSomething&arg=value
```

How the presence of a PHP file named as the first part of my rewrite pattern can break it all?

Comment: According to your rule, the file xml.php can not be executed only with xml.php?arg=value. Are there another rules on the server? Do they collide?

Comment: @Stasik If I not pass the *action* param to `xml.php`, the PHP is executed and it does nothing; anyway, I can't see how can `xml.php` behavior affect the rewrite engine. And **no**, I don't have any other rules on the server; the whole `.htaccess` is exactly the three lines I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. The problem is that I had `Options MultiViews` in my virtual host configuration. I did not know about this option:

> A MultiViews search is enabled by the `MultiViews Options`. If the server receives a request for `/some/dir/foo` and `/some/dir/foo` does *not* exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named `foo.*`

That simply explain why my rule does not work.

Comment: Yup IMO MultiViews are a pain in the \*\*se, and should be disabled by default.